# Photoshop: Border around complex transparent image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, borders

could someone give me a hint how I could draw a border around a transparent image of a tree without too much effort? I tried creating a duplicate layer and resizing it before merging both layers but due to the image's complex edges, this didn't provide the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share an image or two of what you have / are trying to achieve so that we can better help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to create a border around a cut object (a tree in your case) is to right *click on the layer* > *select Blending Options* > *Stroke*.

*[You can also access Blending Options from the Layer tab > Layer Style > Blending options]*

The Stroke menu will look something like this:

[image]

You can adjust the size, position, blend mode, opacity and color of the stroke along with changing the *Fill Type* from **color** to **pattern** or **gradient**.